# React Native - How do I check if URL is a valid Image

Tags: react-native

In React Native, how do I check if a given URL is a valid image?

For example, if the url is https://stackoverflow.com/, it should return **false**. And if it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVHF5.jpg, it should return **true**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
checkValidUrl = (url) => {
//define some image formats 
var types = ['jpg','jpeg','tiff','png','gif','bmp'];

//split the url into parts that has dots before them
var parts = url.split('.');

//get the last part 
var extension = parts[parts.length-1];

//check if the extension matches list 
if(types.indexOf(extension) !== -1) {
    return true;   
}
}

console.log(checkValidUrl("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
checkValidURLImage(){

        var a = "https://i.imgur.com/qMUWuXV.jpg"; //your url

        var b = ["jpeg","jpg","png","gif","raw"]; //format img

        var c = a.split("."); // ["https://i", "imgur", "com/qMUWuXV", "jpg"]

        console.log(b.includes(c[c.length-1]))
}
```